# Undefined symbol _GULResetLogger in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have an iOS app which depends on Facebook SDK , Firebase and Alamofire. I have attached the pod file, according to one of the thread on GitHub issue I have added GoogleUtilities but still it throws the same errors.

```html
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GULResetLogger", referenced from:
      _FIRResetLogger in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerRegisterVersion", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerInitializeASL", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      _FIRLogBasic in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerEnableSTDERR", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerForceDebug", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULSceneDelegateSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
  "_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRIsLoggableLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRSetLoggerLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRApp.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthAPNSTokenManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRBundleUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the pod file for the same

```html
target 'TestApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestApp

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0'
pod 'Bond'
pod 'Purchases', :git => 'https://github.com/daneal/RevenueCat.git'
 

pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'PromisedFuture'
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '~> 6.6.0'

end
```

Any pointers will help in understanding issue and resolving it thanks

Comment: All above methods are present and are 'extern' but somehow they are not getting linked .

Comment: see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5801

Comment: @PaulBeusterien thanks for revert but in my case issue is with simulator as well, havent tried building for device yet .

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I am facing the same issue on simulator but on device its running perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was porting a project from Carthage to cocoa pods and some leftover build files were present from Carthage ( Carthage directory) this was causing build issues, I think this itself explains it. After removing it and rebuilding , everything went fine. Might help someone .

Answer (score 1):

add the following line to your pod file

```
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

source: https://rnfirebase.io/#allow-ios-static-frameworks